# Array declarator in Fortran with no lower bound and upper bound 0

Tags: fortran

According to the Fortran standards information I could find (F77,F90/95) an array declarator where there is no lower bound assumes that this lower bound is 1.  As the upper bound needs to be larger than or equal to the lower bound, this would make the following statement not allowed:

```
INTEGER A(0)
```

However, I cannot make ifort nor gfortran complain in any way about that statement.  Is the compiler not required to flag this as an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As the upper bound needs to be larger than or equal to the lower bound, this would make the following statement not allowed.

From Fortran 2008 Standard:

> **5.3.8.2 Explicit-shape array**
>   [...]
>   3 The values of each lower-bound and upper-bound determine the bounds of the array along a particular dimension and hence the extent of the array in that dimension. If lower-bound appears it species the lower bound; otherwise the lower bound is 1. The value of a lower bound or an upper bound may be positive, negative, or zero. The subscript range of the array in that dimension is the set of integer values between and including the lower and upper bounds, provided the upper bound is not less than the lower bound. ***If the upper bound is less than the lower bound, the range is empty, the extent in that dimension is zero, and the array is of zero size.***

Comment: thnx!  However, i didn't find that particular last sentence in the F77 and F90/95 specifications I looked up...  Well, I'll accept this as an answer, assuming it doens't really matter too much and apparently in later standards it's allowed.

Comment: It's there in F90 and F95. Only F77 explicitly disallows the upper bound to be less than the lower bound.

Comment: Thnx, then my sources where referring only F77 after all.  Still, gfortran with -std=legacy doesn't complain.

Comment: That is because -std=legacy doesn't specify F77. From the documentation: "The default value for std is 'gnu', which specifies a superset of the Fortran 95 standard that includes all of the extensions supported by GNU Fortran, although warnings will be given for obsolete extensions not recommended for use in new code. The 'legacy' value is equivalent but without the warnings for obsolete extensions, and may be useful for old non-standard programs."

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I coded fortran, but I seem to recall that if only one number is supplied, it gives the *length* of the array (with the lower and upper bounds implicitly becoming 1 and `length`). So your code creates a zero-length array.

Comment: Yes, this would indeed mean that my statement is equivalent to `INTEGER A(1:0)`, but my problem is that the compiler doesn't mind.  Even `INTEGER A(10:0)` is accepted.  The only problem is that when you try to access such an array, it will always give an out of bounds error.

Comment: @steabert: I see you point, as the equivalence holds. But you could try to think of `INTEGER A(lower, upper)` as saying "`A` is an array where no indices lower than `lower` are legal, and no indices higher than `upper` are legal". If `lower > upper`, then no indices are legal, as you say. However, there are perfectly valid reasons for having zero-length arrays. Consider e.g. a function that takes an integer array as a parameter and is supposed to return all integers that satisfy a certain criterion. If no such integers are found, a zero-length array would be the natural thing to return.

Comment: I don't think it's right to think of it as specifying the length if only one number is given. The number may also be negative.

Comment: @eriktous and @steabert: Fair enough; I see that it might be more reasonable to interpret it as an upper bound.